# Uncaught ReferenceError: Exchange is not defined

Tags: cordova, sharepoint-2013, visual-studio-2015, office365-apps

I'm running a blank Cordova app in Visual Studio 2015 with two functions I've added while following this tutorial: [Deep Dive: Integrate Office 365 APIs in Your Mobile Device Apps](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/deep-dive-integrate-office-365-apis-in-your-mobile-device-apps-8411?m=11495)

I'm getting this error during run-time:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Exchange is not defined

I've done a bit of searching and can't seem to find much information related to this. I'm always new at this so I might not be looking into the right places. Does this mean I am missing some function title, "Exchange"? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my index.js file

```
(function () {
"use strict";


document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    $("#cmdGetContacts").click(onGetContacts);


    function onGetContacts() {
        var authContext = new O365Auth.Context();
        authContext.getIdToken("https://outlook.office365.com/").then(function (token) {
            var accessTokenFn = token.getAccessTokenFn('https://outlook.office365.com');
            var client = new Exchange.Client('http://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata', accessTokenFn);
            client.me.contacts.getContacts().getch().then(onContactsReceived);

        })
    }

    function onContactsReceived(contacts) {
        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.currentPage.length; i++) {
            var currentContact = contacts.currentPage[i];
            var currentContactname =
                currentContact.surname + ", " + currentContact.givenName;
            var contactDiv = $("<div>").text(currentContactName);
            $("#Status").append(contactDiv);

        }
    }


    function notifyClick() {
        console.log("the link has been linked boss.");

    }

};



function onPause() {
    // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
};

function onResume() {
    // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
};
} )();
```

And this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--
    Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed.     Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
    For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<title>Office365Test3</title>

<!-- Office365Test3 references -->
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Test 3</p>
<br />
<a href="#" id="mylink">Link</a>
<br />
<button id="cmdGetContacts">Button</button>
<div id="Status"></div>
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
<script src="services/office365/settings/settings.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/utility.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/sharepoint.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/o365loader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/o365discovery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/o365auth.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/InAppBrowserOverride.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/exchange.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/aadgraph.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference error means it tried to use a variable called Exchange but it was not defined. In your code it concerns the following code:

```
var client = new Exchange.Client('http://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata', accessTokenFn);
```

Are you sure exchange.js actually exists at the *scripts/exchange.js* path and if that library defines the Exchange keyword. Please confirm if the file is loaded into your page.